# Is this the correct way to do private functions in Javascript / node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

A class I'm writing in node.js is as below:

```
module.exports = exports = function(){ return new ClassA() };

function ClassA(){
    this.myvariable = 0;
}
```

I have a function that I want to be private. To my understanding if the function is declared outside of the constructor, it will essentially be a static function which wouldn't be able to reference this.myvariable.

Is the correct way of dealing with this to declare the function within the constructor like this:

```
//within constructor
this.myFunction = function myFunction(){
    console.log(this.myvariable)
}
```

Or is there a better way of doing it that doesn't leave me with a potentially huge constructor?

EDIT: It looks like I've misunderstood something here because the above code doesn't even work...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simplest way to have a private function is to just declare a function outside of the class. The prototype functions can still reference it perfectly fine, and pass their `this` scope with `.call()`

```
function privateFunction() {
  console.log(this.variable)
}

var MyClass = function () {
  this.variable = 1;
}

MyClass.prototype.publicMethod = function() {
  privateFunction.call(this);
}

var x = new MyClass();
x.publicMethod()
```

Answer (score 13):

**Update from May 17, 2019**

In ESNext, which is the next specification of javascript, the support of private methods and attributes has been added.

To make an attribute or a function private, use the character `#`.

```js
class Foo {
    #privateAttribute = 'hey';

    showPrivate() {
        console.log(this.#privateAttribute);
    }
}
```

---

It has been implemented in node.js v12+.

---

You can configure babel to transpile it using the following [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-private-methods).

It requires babel v7.0.0+.

Comment: Using arrow function you can also define private methods like properties `#privateMethod = () => { ... code ... }`

Comment: Private instance variables can be declared like: `this.#privateVar = 'asdf';`. You can also define private functions by just naming them with a `#` at the start. `#privateMethod() {...}`. 
Doesn't have to be using `#a = () => {...}`

Answer (score 7):

Whatever you will not add to `module.exports`  will be private for that `module` and can not be accessed from outside of the module.
Also inside the controller store the reference of `this` into a local variable

```
var self = this;
```

You can use revealing module pattern.

```
var myNameSpace = function() {
    var current = null;
    function init() {
        …
    }
    function change() {
        …
    }
    function verify() {
        …
    }
    return{
        init:init,
        change:change
    }
}();
module.exports = exports = myNameSpace;
```

This way `init` and `change` will be `public` and verify will be private.

You can see Douglas Crockford style of making private members.
http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

**Edit**
Douglas Crockford's link has been changed now.
new link http://crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make a private method, but it can't be part of the prototype

```
function ClassA()
{
    var myvariable;

    var private = function()   // This is private method
    {
        myvariable = 0;
    }

    this.public = function()   // This is public method
    {
        private();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript **Public Functions**

```
ClassA.prototype.myFunction = function (string) {
   //your logic
}
```

another type of public function

```
 function ClassA(){
    this.myvariable = 0;

    var MyFunction3 = function () {
       //your logic
    };
    this.MyFunction2 = function () {
        //your logic
    };
 }
```

javascript **Private Function**

```
function ClassA() {

    function MyFunction() {
       //your logic
   }
}
```

I would like to prefer to visit [this link](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) that will describe you every well.

Answer (score 0):

In fact ,there are not class in javascript.
Look a json object constructor:

```
var ClassA=function() {
    this.publicFunction=function (){
        console.log("public function");
    }
    function privateFunction(){
        console.log("private function");
    }
    return this;
}
```

then you use new to create a ClassA:

```
var a=new ClassA();
```

you can use the publicFunction, but you can't use the privateFunction like it's private.

```
a.publicFunction();
a.privateFunction();//you can't do this
```

Any help for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
//  NOT A CLASS just a "regular-file.js"

    function A(){}    
    function B(){}
    function C(){}
    module.exports = {
      A,
      B
    }

// Using the functions 

    let function = require('location of regular-file.js')
    function.A()
    function.B()
```

Function C is NOT exposed and therefore it is private

***************** Private functions in a Class ***************

```
function outsideClass(){}

class MyClass{
  function insideClass(){
    outsideClass()  //  calling the function outside of the class
  }
}

module.exports = {MyClass}

//  using the functions in the class
let myClass = require('MyClass')
let mc = new myClass()
mc.insideClass()
```

The function outsideClass() is not exposed and therefore private